# configure FreeRADIUS rlm_rest module in CentOS

Tags: freeradius

I want to construct a 2 factor authentication system using freeRADIUS for proxy and privacyIDEA for authentication in server. I read some documents about  freeRADIUS  and privacyIDEA, and find that rlm_rest module could be helpful for this. I find this document in privacyIDEA webside:
http://privacyidea.readthedocs.io/en/master/application_plugins/rlm_rest.html#rlm-rest

and it just show how to install rlm_rest module in Ubuntu using apt-get, but my server is CentOS 7. So my first question is:

How to install the required packages of rlm_rest module in CentOS?

After that ,the document shows the configuration steps:

```
The authentication type needs to be configured in the /etc/freeradius/users file:

DEFAULT Auth-Type := rest

and the site configuration should invoke the module as follows:
authenticate {
    Auth-Type rest {
       rest
    }
    digest
    unix
}
```

And I don`t know where I should invoke the “authenticate {…}”module? Does it should be write in /etc/freeradius/users ? This is my second question.

Could you please give me some advice or some references? Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `authenticate`  section goes to your **site** configuration.
Also on CentOS this would be located in /etc/raddb/sites-enabled, which is linked to *sites-available*.

You should consider using the `rlm_perl` module, since this is more flexible.
http://privacyidea.readthedocs.io/en/master/application_plugins/rlm_perl.html#rlm-perl